# bleak, read_gatt_char() couldn't update the value from Arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I'm trying to get the signal from Arduino nano 33 ble to python code.
So I used read_gatt_char() of bleak library. this code can read the bytes from the Arduino, but It doesn't change, even if I can see the change in the bluetooth terminal(LightBlue).

this is the output of the code in terminal

```
Connected: True
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

this is the signal from Arduino in bluetooth terminal..

*the signal from Arduino in bluetooth terminal*
[image: the signal from Arduino in bluetooth terminal]

```py
import sys
import asyncio
import platform

from bleak import BleakClient


CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "00001143-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

ADDRESS = (
    "3c:22:fb:29:21:3d"
    if platform.system() != "Darwin"
    else "EF670BB4-B0D8-353D-ACCE-4405567E8391"
)

def notification_handler(data):
    """Simple notification handler which prints the data received."""
    output_numbers = list(data)
    print(output_numbers)


async def main(address):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    async with BleakClient(address, use_cached=False) as client:
        print(f"Connected: {client.is_connected}")

        while True:
            value = bytes(await client.read_gatt_char(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID))

            await client.start_notify(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, notification_handler(value))
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await client.stop_notify(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    asyncio.run(
        main(
            sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else ADDRESS
            # sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
        )
    )
    try:
        asyncio.ensure_future(main(), loop=loop)
        loop.run_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
        print("User stopped program.")
```